# Update geometry(polygon) of shapefile based on a point layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry

I have two shapefiles.

1. Polygon shapefile
2. Point file contains some points.

Now I want to delete all the vertex of polygon shapefile which are available in point file.

I am using ArcGIS (ArcEditor) platform.

Any ideas?

---

This is result of procedure you have mentioned via GeoWizard.

Till now I have not deleted any point, just converted polygons to point and then point to polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

via **GeoWizards**

Polygon To Point (with Vertices option)

combine (merge) both point files

select duplicate points - delete them.

rebuild polygons with Point To Polygon

Advantage is the attributes from the original polygon are preserved through the new point file

http://www.ian-ko.com/

Comment: +1.  At first glance it seems this would not work, but Ianko wisely records the original order of the polygon points in *Polygon To Point* so that *Point To Polygon" can use this to reconnect the vertices in the correct sequence.

Comment: Hence why I use Geo-wizards more often than ArcGIS Tools - Ianko tools work more efficiently and have had better results with his tools. Only Safe Software's FME gives more control over feature manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my initial thinking (I'm not sure to what extent ArcGIS can help with tools to do these steps):

1. Create a point layer from the polygon vertices, with additional fields to track polygon and vertex order.
2. Select from the above layer using the original point layer, and then delete those vertices.
3. Recreate the new polygon layer.

Comment: your initial thinking is absolutely right but i was looking for some tool (if available) before building my own.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all those who has participated in this thread
For those who are interested in the solution, i am using Manifold to do this. Here is thread
http://www.georeference.org/forum/t108320#108357
An other reason for me start working in manifold.